# Is there any doc listing standard <=> Oracle character sets correspondencies?

Tags: oracle, character-set

I'm looking for a table listing Oracle and "standard" character sets, for example:

```
Oracle       Standard
------------ ----------
WEISO98859P1 iso-8859-1
AL32UTF8     utf-8
etc.         etc.
```

Does this kind of resource exist? I couldn't find any.

Comment: Were you able to find a mapping for all the names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is covered by the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/applocaledata.htm#i634381)

Comment: Thank you... Not as complete as I expected (e.g. only "recommended Oracle charsets" are listed), but it's far better than nothing :)

Answer (score 4):

Someone tried to create what I'm looking for:

http://ruby-oci8.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/ruby-oci8/lib/oci8/encoding.yml

Without comments & unknown values:

```
JA16EUC:           EUC-JP
JA16EUCTILDE:      CP51932      # or eucJP-ms
JA16SJIS:          Shift_JIS
JA16SJISTILDE:     Windows-31J
KO16MSWIN949:      CP949
TH8TISASCII:       Windows-874  # or TIS-620
VN8MSWIN1258:      Windows-1258
ZHS16GBK:          GBK
ZHT16HKSCS:        [CP951, Big5-HKSCS, Big5]
ZHT16MSWIN950:     [CP950, Big5]
ZHT32EUC:          EUC-TW       # Who use this?

BLT8ISO8859P13:    ISO-8859-13
BLT8MSWIN1257:     Windows-1257
CL8ISO8859P5:      ISO-8859-5
CL8MSWIN1251:      Windows-1251
EE8ISO8859P2:      ISO-8859-2
EL8ISO8859P7:      ISO-8859-7
EL8MSWIN1253:      Windows-1253
EE8MSWIN1250:      Windows-1250
NE8ISO8859P10:     ISO-8859-10
NEE8ISO8859P4:     ISO-8859-4
WE8ISO8859P15:     ISO-8859-15
WE8MSWIN1252:      Windows-1252

AR8ISO8859P6:      ISO-8859-6
AR8MSWIN1256:      Windows-1256
IW8ISO8859P8:      ISO-8859-8
IW8MSWIN1255:      Windows-1255
TR8MSWIN1254:      Windows-1254
WE8ISO8859P9:      ISO-8859-9

AL32UTF8:          UTF-8

KO16KSC5601:       EUC-KR # This should be 'CP949'?
TH8MACTHAIS:       macThai
ZHS16CGB231280:    GB2312
ZHT16BIG5:         Big5
ZHT16HKSCS31:      [CP951, Big5-HKSCS, Big5]

IW8PC1507:         IBM862
TR8PC857:          IBM857
BLT8PC775:         IBM775
CDN8PC863:         IBM863
CEL8ISO8859P14:    ISO-8859-14
CL8KOI8R:          KOI8-R
CL8KOI8U:          KOI8-U
CL8MACCYRILLICS:   macCyrillic
EE8MACCES:         macCentEuro
EE8MACCROATIANS:   macCroatian
EE8PC852:          IBM852       # or 'CP852'
EL8MACGREEKS:      macGreek
EL8PC869:          IBM869
IS8PC861:          IBM861
N8PC865:           IBM865
RU8PC855:          IBM855 # or 'CP855'
RU8PC866:          IBM866
SE8ISO8859P3:      ISO-8859-3
TR8MACTURKISH:     macTurkish
TR8MACTURKISHS:    macTurkish
US7ASCII:          US-ASCII
US8PC437:          IBM437
WE8ISO8859P1:      ISO-8859-1
WE8MACROMAN8S:     macRoman
WE8PC850:          CP850
WE8PC860:          IBM860
UTF8:              UTF-8

JA16MACSJIS:       MacJapanese
TH8MACTHAI:        macThai
ZHS32GB18030:      GB18030
CL8MACCYRILLIC:    macCyrillic
EE8MACCROATIAN:    macCroatian
EE8MACCE:          macCentEuro
EL8PC737:          IBM737
EL8MACGREEK:       macGreek
IS8MACICELANDICS:  macIceland
IS8MACICELANDIC:   macIceland
WE8MACROMAN8:      macRoman

AL16UTF16:         UTF-16BE
AL16UTF16LE:       UTF-16LE
```

Answer (score 2):

You should get a complete list with this query:

```
SELECT VALUE, UTL_I18N.MAP_CHARSET(VALUE) AS IANA_VALUE
FROM V$NLS_VALID_VALUES 
WHERE parameter = 'CHARACTERSET'  
ORDER BY IANA_VALUE, VALUE;
```